# Error using Settings file.

Tags: c#, settings

I'm trying to use a settings file in VS 2013 to store the text of textBox1.Text and then re-input it when you open the application again.

I have it setup like this.

Settings file is here: http://i.gyazo.com/e3aef293c3b8dbdfab269718de81a310.png

On public Form1() I have this to read the text.

```
    textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.aaa;
```

then on saving it I have it like this.

```
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.aaa = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

But I get the error

```
 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'aaa' and no extension method 'aaa' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you debugged through to ensure the textBox1 HAS text ? Also is the reading of the text working ?\

Comment: neither works and both give the same error.

Comment: where do you save the settings ?? Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Comment: It's within the checkBox code. I should've mentioned, that doesn't give an error.

Comment: check the namespace in the codefile which has been generated. I have noticed this can get out of whack before.

Comment: Couldn't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Does the code even compile? That error message happens at compile time, no?

Comment: No it doesn't compile because of the error. When I remove the lines of code it does.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The issue was that Settings.settings was in both the Properties folder and the root folder. I replaced the one in the Properties folder with the other one. I think this issue can occur if you unload and reload a Project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had added the names to the settings file, but not to the visual studio project. All I had to do was to go to the Solution explorer, Under properties, double click the settings.settings (has a wheel icon) and it auto generated the missing code.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the namespace of the setting file changed when I migrated to .Net core.